# How do I update thunkable data viewer value with an int?

Tags: app-inventor

how do I update a thunkable data viewer value with an integer? it seems like it only accepts a string.

[image]
This does not work

Comment: there is no Thunkable X category here in Stackoverflow... and App Inventor is something completely different (it also uses blocks, but that's the only thing both have in common)... I suggest you to ask in the Thunkable X community here https://community.thunkable.com/

Comment: Thunkable will convert ints to strings for you when neccessary - I got this to work with a table data source. What type is your data source? Check that your row id is what you expect and that the data viewer component is looking at the same data referenced here.